# What colours can the Bella Cantata bloom in Streetpass Garden?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-garden-flower-town

I want to grow the Bella Cantata in all colours but I don't know what the other two colours are! I have grown it in purple and white, but I'm not sure what other ones there could be...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_flowers_in_Flower_Town), the four colors are White, Light Blue, Purple, and Pink.

Here's what they look like:

[image: White][image: Light Blue][image: Purple][image: Pink]